# How do you get "the Hustler" award in gta online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

The Hustler award is given once you win 50K through betting.  If I bet a little on everybody on a single race, do my winnings net out or does it count the bet that I *did* win?  If I win 1000 one race and lose 1000 next race, do i need to earn another 50k or 49k to pop the award?

For example, here is my friend's progress towards the award compared to the amount of earnings from betting he has.  It doesn't add up.

[image: betting cash earned]
[image: progress towards Hustler]

Comment: Im almost positive it is the total amount won.  But I am trying to find source to this, but farming this seems to be really easy with 1 other person.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to be cash earned from betting to get this achievement as you can see your progress on the Rockstar Social Club progress section.   Below is a screenshot of my current cash earned (notice betting is a category):

[image]